# Python apscheduler start function immediately, Not starting on given time?

Tags: python, apscheduler

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from GoogleSheetAPI import writedata
sched = BlockingScheduler()

sched.add_job(writedata,'corn' day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=10, minute=30)
sched.start()
```

its start function immediately, it is not waiting for the given time. I am trying to run this on every Monday to Friday on 10:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two typos in your function call:

```
sched.add_job(writedata, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=10, minute=30)
```

If that doesn't work, [add extended logging](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#troubleshooting) to your code.